# why isn't variable value available outside loop

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm a newbie to node.js but an old hand at programming.  I am getting values from a query and putting them into an array.  The values are available in the array creation, but not outside.  Console log "new data" shows point[0] has a value.  console log point[0] (third line from end) shows undefined. Here is my code.

```
    var polygon = [-89.72,34.27,-89.46,34.53,-89.44,34.53,-89.43,34.52];
    var point = [];
    con.connect(function (err) {
        console.log("Connected4 " + polygon);
        var sql = 'select customer_num, latitude,longitude from gc.customers';  
        console.log("SQL = " + sql);
        con.query(sql, function (err, rows, fields) {
            if (err) throw err;
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {       
                   point[0] = rows[i].latitude;
                   point[1] = rows[i].longitude;
                   console.log("new row " + point[0] + " newpoint " + point[1]);                                
            }                      
        });                  
        console.log("point0= ", point[0], "polygon0 = ", polygon[0])
        const inside = require("point-in-polygon")(point, polygon)
        console.log('inside = ' + inside)
    });
```

Here is my console log

```
node junksql.js
Connected4 -89.72,34.27,-89.46,34.53,-89.44,34.53,-89.43,34.52
SQL = select customer_num, latitude,longitude from gc.customers
point0=  undefined polygon0 =  -89.72
inside=  false point0=  undefined vs0 =  -89.72
inside = false
new row 28.406973 newpoint -81.57685
new row 28.406973 newpoint -81.57685
new row 28.472523 newpoint -81.473743
new row 28.406973 newpoint -81.57685
new row 28.406973 newpoint -81.57685
new row 28.406973 newpoint -81.57685
new row 28.472523 newpoint -81.473743
new row 28.472523 newpoint -81.473743
^C
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's undefined because its outside of the callback function for `con.query`. What's happening here is that your code will not wait for the callback to complete, so when it reaches the line `con.query(sql, function (err, rows, fields) {` it will then move on to `console.log("point0= ", point[0], "polygon0 = ", polygon[0]` while the callback block is evaluated. There are a few ways around this. Here is one fix that implements [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

```
const sqlQuery = (query) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        con.query(query, function (err, rows, fields) {
            if (err) return reject(err);
            return resolve (rows);
        });
    });
};

const polygon = [-89.72,34.27,-89.46,34.53,-89.44,34.53,-89.43,34.52];
let point = [];

con.connect(function (err) {
   sqlQuery('select customer_num, latitude,longitude from gc.customers')
        .then(results => {
            for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                //note: this is probably not the best logic
                point[0] = results[i].latitude;
                point[1] = results[i].longitude;
            }
            const shape = require("point-in-polygon")(point, polygon);
            //do stuff with, or return, shape
        })
        .catch(err => {
            //handle error
        });
});
```

Note that looping through the results, but assigning the values to `point[0]` and `point[1]` means that if you have multiple results, only the last pair will be set. Depending on what you expect to happen here, there are better ways to structure this portion.

The key change I made here is I wrapped the query with a Promise. This allows us to determine where exactly to resolve or reject the logic within the promise. When a promise is returned, you can either `await` it with [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) or you can use [`Promise.prototype.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) to wait for the returned value.

Comment: Thank you.  This answers my question and I better understand what is going on.  This is just a small piece of some much larger code.  I am eventually trying to determine which customers are within the polygon I define and which aren't.

Answer (score 0):

As you can clearly see from your `console.log` that everything outside of your query is running first.

This is what is called `Asynchronous behavior`. Which basically means you cannot get values outside from a function that runs `Asynchronously` because Javascript/Node.js is Synchronous languages (Single Thread) and it does not wait for you `async function` to finish and `console log` whatever value it currently holds which by default is `undefined`.

People get confused on this behaviour a lot and you might want to understand how Node.Js and async stuff is handled by [Event Loop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ)

Comment: Thanks.  I do need to educate myself more on this behavior.